# Image recognition puzzle: Which off-the-shelf WPF library is this program using for its GUI?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I'm really curious to know which off-the-shelf WPF library [this program](http://www.vectorvest.com/products/vvrt.aspx) is using for its web interface.

I'd like to use a few of the components in a small, in-house .NET program I'm writing.

Here is a couple of images showing the [program in question](http://www.vectorvest.com/products/vvrt.aspx) (and if you don't know what WPF library this one is based on, please feel free to recommend your favourite).

[image: http://www.microchipc.com/vectorvest/image1.png]

[image]

Comment: Get a copy / trial. Look at the dll's downloaded. Third party components have very recognizable names (after all there are only some players there anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a copy / trial. Look at the dll's downloaded. Third party components have very recognizable names (after all there are only some players there anyway).